# Cannot find root cause of an error "outlined release of model"

Tags: ios, swift, combine

I have a consistent crash that I cannot find the solution for. In one of the modal views in my application, the user could create several cards and when the user is "DONE", I collect the created cards and POST them one by one(The modal view will dismissed). I have a Alamofire/ Combine POST call below that saves info on one card a user creates. When I try to post the data, I get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` on the commented line in the code.

I have many other GET and POST calls that work correctly that has very similar method bodies, this is the only method I know of that is throwing the error.

```
class APIHandler {
    ...
    
    func postAdditionalCard(data: String) throws -> AnyPublisher<Card_AdditionalPostResponse, Error> {
        
        let postCardAdditionalReq = Card_AdditionalPostRequest(data: data)
        
        let paramData = try JSONEncoder().encode(postCardAdditionalReq)
        let params = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: paramData, options: [])
        
        return try networking.authorizationHeader() //Helper that fetches, either locally or remotely,
                // the Authorization token and creates a authorization header with it
            .flatMap { authHeader -> AnyPublisher<Card_AdditionalPostResponse, Error> in
                
                self.networking.decodablePublisher(URL.cardAdditional, method: .post, parameters: params as? [String: Any], headers: [authHeader])
                    .mapError { _ in LANet.LANetError.genericError }
                    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
            }
            .eraseToAnyPublisher() //stack trace highlights this line with "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"
    }
    ...
}
```

The `Card_AdditionalPostRequest` struct

```
public struct Card_AdditionalPostRequest: Codable {
    
    let ucc_id: Int?
    let ucc_user_id: String
    let ucc_created_time: String?
    let ucc_description: String?
    let ucc_type: String
    
    public init(createdCard: Common_UserCard, task: Common_Task) {
        
        self.ucc_id = createdCard.ucc_id?.intValue
        self.ucc_user_id = createdCard.ucc_user_id ?? ""
        self.ucc_created_time = createdCard.ucc_created_time?.yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_SecString
        self.ucc_description = createdCard.ucc_description
        self.ucc_type = createdCard.ucc_type ?? ""
    }
}
```

The exception as shown in the debug navigator

```
#0  swift_release
#1  0x0000000103306c5f in outlined release of Card_AdditionalPostRequest ()
...
```

NOTE :

1. `networking` is a simple wrapper around Alamofire.
2. The class APIHandler is not tied to the lifecycle of a view, but to the entire app (i.e. created when the app is booted up).
3. `Card_AdditionalPostResponse` is like any other model. A struct conforming to `Codable` and has some data in it.
4. the `parameters` variable is optional and if I remove `parameters: params as? [String: Any],` from the network call, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` exception vanishes, but the additional data would not be attached in the call.

Comment: First of all I suggest adding Card_AdditionalPostRequest struct to the answer,
Secondly you can debug the publisher modifiers with modifiers called .print(), .breakpoint , .breakpointOnError and .handleEvents in order to understand what exactly is your issue

Comment: @AvivFrenkel I've added the struct; the exception is not thrown during the Alamofire response callback, but while creating the publisher. Thanks